# 2 passports same country

Tags: passports

I'm Indonesian and live in philippines, I have passport A and still valid for 3 years, recently I went home to my country to apply for passport B with purpose to add last name on it. Since I just stayed for a while and passport B not yet come out, I went back to philippines using my passport A. My plan is ask somebody to send passport B to philippines via courier when it come out.

1. Will this be okay for me to get out from philippines and to enter indonesia or other country using my passport B?
2. Or do I need to go back to indonesia first using passport A and get out again using passport B?
3. When they issue passport B, will my passport A immediately detected as invalid in customs dabatase?

Comment: For clarity, is your question about a renewed passport, or using two passports (dual-nationality)? The references to A and B are confusing

Comment: Its renewed passport, both passports issued by same country (indonesia)

Comment: I think it varies by country. If you're concerned, you could ask the authorities (such as calling the Philippines embassy in Indonesia). Or you could wait until you receive passport B, then travel with both and explain the reason to the border officer.